# How to Open Google Map Using Intent from an App and navigate Automatically to showing route and Distance between two points

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I have tried by this way but it does not navigate Automatically to this point.

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+"22.541035,88.356366"+"&daddr="+"22.541251,88.347414";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
 public static void showRouteOnMap(Context mContext, String lat, String lng) {
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + lat + "," + lng);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
```

Pass latitude and longitude of the destination location.

Answer (score 0):

Your can you this it will draw route on google map from your current location you can change it as you want

```
    private void googleMapDirectionIntent(String destination) {
        Uri.Builder directionsBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme("https")
                .authority("www.google.com")
                .appendPath("maps")
                .appendPath("dir")
                .appendPath("")
                .appendQueryParameter("api", "1")
                .appendQueryParameter("destination", "" + destination);

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, directionsBuilder.build()));
    }
```

Hope it Helps.